# Java Find Grid and FloodFill on BufferedImage

Tags: java, ocr, bufferedimage, image-segmentation, flood-fill

I had a problem when I try to segmentation board game with first try to find grid and floodfill. But i stuck, i flood all pixel white to red and i don't know how to ONLY fill the grid no number or other to fill just gridline.

My current result like this [image]

and i want to fill like this [image]

and this code i use `

```
boolean flood(BufferedImage img, boolean[][] mark,
                             int row, int col, Color srcColor, Color tgtColor) {
```

// make sure row and col are inside the image
    if (row < 0) return false;
    if (col < 0) return false;
    if (row >= img.getHeight()) return false;
    if (col >= img.getWidth()) return false;

    // make sure this pixel hasn't been visited yet
    if (mark[row][col]) return false;

    Color asli = new Color(img.getRGB(col, row));
    // make sure this pixel is the right color to fill
    if (!asli.equals(srcColor)) return false;

    // fill pixel with target color and mark it as visited
    img.setRGB(col, row, tgtColor.getRGB());
    mark[row][col] = true;

    // recursively fill surrounding pixels
    flood(img, mark, row - 1, col, srcColor, tgtColor);
    flood(img, mark, row + 1, col, srcColor, tgtColor);
    flood(img, mark, row, col - 1, srcColor, tgtColor);
    flood(img, mark, row, col + 1, srcColor, tgtColor);

    return true;        
}

 boolean[][] mark = new boolean[citra.getHeight()][citra.getWidth()];

        for (int y = 0; y < citra.getHeight(); y++)
        {          
            for (int x = 0; x < citra.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                Color warna = new Color(citra.getRGB(x, y));
                if (warna.equals(Color.WHITE)){
                    flood(citra, mark, x, y, Color.WHITE, Color.RED);
                    break;
                }  
           }
        }

        imagebiner.setIcon(new ImageIcon(citra.getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        repaint();

i hope anyone can help find solution for problem like this.

Comment: Please consider clarifying what is it you are trying to accomplish. Images are great, buy it is still difficult trying to understand which part is working and which part does not

Comment: i try to fill only the grid or the outerbox NOT fill the number or other, but i don't know how? my purprose is to find line and corner later but i must solve to fill outerbox with other color first i think @bc004346

Answer (score 0):

That would largely depend on whether you have the same Image layout every time or not. If you supply the same format as in your sample image that the task is straight forward:

- Keep track of where lines are (since those are static)
- Go through the whole image without changing colors
- Keep a two-dimensional array `B`with the size of 9 by 9
- One you detect a number (non-source color), mark the corresponding `B` item as taken.
- After the first pass only color spaces in between lines that are marked as not taken in your `B` array.

If image size and layout are dynamic then you need to have an extra step (ahead of logic above) of determining where lines are. This is more complex, but not by too much:

- Make a pass through the whole image keeping track of differently-colored pixels.
- Once you have that, you can determine lines by comparing X and Y values. If X increments while Y is the same, then you have horizontal line. If Y is static while X increments through the whole image, you have a vertical line.

Comment: sorry i don't understand your explanation. How i know the pixels which form the number? and the image size is same because i use rescalling but layout is dynamic. can you explain how to keep track the pixel and floodfill only the grid with some pseudocode or example maybe. thank you @bc004346

Comment: @VictorChandra Are you looking for a complete solution or help on a specific, small problem? Is this your own code above? Do you understand it?

Comment: yes that is my own code, i had try to find grid with coloring the grid to red but my problem is the pixel which form the number and other pixel noise too fill with red. My step is : first i binary the image to black and white with threshold slider, and next i track the pixel and if find first white pixel i use function floodfill to fill it with red and recursive of the neighbourhood pixel. do you understand what i mean? i hope anyone can help me to find the logic to fill only the grid (segmentation the box) @bc004346

Comment: Why is the image crooked? Do you work on scanned pages or is this a photo of your screen?

Comment: do you mean source image of puzzle? that is image i get on internet, i try any images puzzle because like i tell before layout(image puzzle) is dynamic. i try to recognize the puzzle image to array later BUT my problem now is segmentation the box(fill the grid to get first pixel and pixel of the box) @bc004346

Comment: Your approach will not help you. Rather than trying to filling neighboring pixels you need to analyse the whole image to find out where the lines are. Given your example image above that will not be a trivial task because lines will not always be straight. That being said, I'd say that you will probably have to work on the algorithm for a long time and you better have some good justification about why you want to do this.

Comment: This is my assignment to study OCR concept without use library in java to get the puzzle in array. i don't expert maybe but i never stop to learning. Thanks for your advise @bc004346